# sendPasswordResetEmail Firebase Auth method deleting other sign in providers accounts (facebook, github, etc)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

My sign in Method for facebook or github works perfectly fine and they link the account with the user and email account. The problem is that when I execute the recovery password method 'sendPasswordResetEmail' and the user sets a new password, the old facebook/github accounts get deleted and for some reason, It doesnt allow me to link them again.

Has anyone had this problem or does anyone has a solution?

I tried to use linkwithpopup method but it doesnt work once the password gets recovered.

Comment: If you think the Firebase APIs are not working correctly, you should file a bug report with [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) directly.